# How to use Salesforce Sans font in lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system, css, static-resources

I have uploaded the Salesforce Sans font as satic resource in my dev org.

[image]

How to use this sytle in my lightning component.

```
<lightning:layout multipleRows="true">
    <lightning:layoutItem size="12" mediumDeviceSize="5" class="border">
        <div class="slds-box" style="font-family:sans-serif;">
            My first Lightning componet
        </div>
    </lightning:layoutItem>
</lightning:layout>
```

Please help me out !!

Comment: This blog does excatly what you want. http://sfdcmonkey.com/2017/06/22/custom-font-lightning-component-static-resource/

Answer (score 1):

Add a custom css class instead of your inline style (eg. customFont).

```
<p class="customFont"> TEST </p>
```

In your css file add the following:

```
customFont.THIS {
    font-family: 'customSalesforceFont';
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}
@font-face {
   font-family: 'customSalesforceFont';
   src: url(/resource/SalesforceSans-Book); 
}
```